# Why is a density matrix an orthogonal projector?

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, density-matrix

Suppose I have a density matrix like $\rho = \frac{1}{2}[I + \hat{n}\vec{\sigma}]$.

The claim is that $\rho$ is an orthogonal projector for the state $|+\rangle$ in an arbitrary direction $\hat{n}$.

How do I convince myself of this claim?

Answer (score 1):

If a matrix is a projector, it squares to itself. So, you just have to verify that $\rho^2=\rho$. You'll need the assumption that the length of the Bloch vector is 1.

Answer (score 1):

> Suppose I have a density matrix like $\rho = \frac{1}{2}[I + \hat{n}\vec{\sigma}]$.

Explicitly, we have
$$
\rho =
\frac{1}{2}\left(\begin{matrix}
1+n_z & n_x - in_y\\
n_x + in_y & 1 - n_z
\end{matrix}\right)
$$

> The claim is that $\rho$ is an orthogonal projector for the state $|+\rangle$ in an arbitrary direction $\hat{n}$.

> How do I convince myself of this claim?

You can convince yourself based on the well known Bloch sphere expression for a ket in the direction $\hat n$:
$$
|\psi\rangle = \cos(\theta/2)|0\rangle + e^{i\phi}\sin(\theta/2)|1\rangle\;,
$$
where
$$
\hat n = (\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi), \sin(\theta)\sin(\phi), \cos(\theta))\;.
$$

Then the density operator is:
$$
\hat \rho = |\psi\rangle\langle\psi|
$$
and, **for example** the (0,0) matrix element of the above operator is:
$$
\rho_{00} = \langle 0|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|0\rangle =  \cos(\theta/2)^2 = \frac{1+\cos(\theta)}{2}\;,
$$
which is the (0,0) element of your original matrix, since:
$$
\begin{align}
\rho &=
\frac{1}{2}\left(\begin{matrix}
1+n_z & n_x - in_y\\
n_x + in_y & 1 - n_z
\end{matrix}\right)\\ 
&=
\frac{1}{2}\left(\begin{matrix}
1+\cos(\theta) & \sin(\theta)(\cos(\phi)) -i\sin(\phi))\\
\sin(\theta)(\cos(\phi)) +i\sin(\phi)) & 1 - \cos(\theta)
\end{matrix}\right)\;.
\end{align}
$$

And so on.